# What's the performance impact of exporting registers to stack?

Tags: performance, assembly, simd, avx, avx2

I am working on some code that is meant to run on x86 in 32-bit mode. In that mode, I understand that I've got only 8 SIMD/AVX2-Registers (YMM0-7) to freely work with. However, some of my vector subroutines alone sometimes use more than that amount of registers simultainiously (meaning that they are still needed somewhere down the road - mostly not so far afterwards).

My understanding is, that compilers will export older registers to **stack memory** when they can't find unused registers. But how much does this impact performance ? (e.g. in cycles per export/import later on). Can I trust in stack memory mostly residing in L1-D-Cache (with 2 cycles latency in Haswell) or is there a significant performance impact of avoiding such register-to-memory (and vice versa) transfers ?

So far I wasn't able to find answers to this topic, especially since the registers keep getting bigger and bigger (1 Cacheline per register with upcoming Skylake platform). It would be nice if you could give sources in case you answer.

Comment: Your code will be slower of course.  If you want to know by how much then simply profile your code, comparing the 32-bit and 64-bit versions.  Only you can do that.

Comment: Out of curiosity. Why are you restricted to 32-bit mode? Core2 came out almost nine years ago. And since Nehalem (2008) macro op fusion works in 64-bit mode. AVX512 which comes out next year will have 32 AVX512 registers in 64-bit mode and only 8 in 32-bit mode. Why would you restrict your code to only 32-bit mode?

Comment: I agree with both of you. It looks like I need to benchmark it to see whether its better to adjust my instrisics. 32-bit support is required because some workstations still run with a 32-bit only operating system. The issue however will be the same, whether its 8 or 16 registers, just less severe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always an impact to hit memory.

A write is generally slow. However, if you only hit the L1 cache, it is close to instantaneous (nearly the same as copying a register to another.) If you hit L2 or L3, that's slower, but still very fast. If you hit actual memory, that's "dead" slow (in comparison.) So if your L1 cache is 12Kb, you can have up to 12Kb of data on your stack and still work really fast (although remember that caches are shared between your data and the code you're running; it may be 6Kb of instruction cache and 6Kb of data including stack.)

The main problem you'll hit is how much memory you're working on. If your input data is very large, that will have the largest impact. Especially if you cannot load the input data in a streaming manner for which processors are well optimized. (read X bytes from (eax), do eax + X, then repeat).

Note that if you have to write it in assembler, you'll have to do all the work that a compiler could do for you with zero errors and fully optimized. Compilers today are really good at optimizing (gcc/g++). It becomes particularly complicated when you PUSH on the stack, changing the offset of all your local variables currently on the stack (unless you use a frame pointer.)

As another detail, compilers see the stack as a structure defined from the set of all the local variables necessary in a function. So accessing the stack is very similar to accessing a structure.

Comment: Which x86 micro-architecture with AVX2 has a **unified** L1 cache of 12kb? Also, it's called "frame pointer" or "base pointer", not "frame buffer".

Comment: I will use C/C++ combined with avx intrinsics. To become more clear: is the memory used for register saving (stack) "hot" (residing in L1) by e.g. getting used nearly all the time ? In theory, compiler vendors should have implemented it this way but I'm not sure because its easy to fill many cachelines with avx registers, especially when it uses aligned stores.

Comment: Yes, in that sense 99.9% of the time your stack will be "hot". That would depend on the operating system more than the compiler (i.e. you could force the stack memory to always be written to RAM). The compiler could be a problem if it spreads the data "more than necessary", but that's unlikely a problem. What you may hit is reading new data that takes the place of your stack in the L1 cache. Now, the cool thing with intrinsic instructions is that you can use labels for registers and the compiler will associate a CPU register automatically giving it a chance to optimize things further.

Comment: I suppose also that what you are thinking is that one AVX register will be using one or two blocks of cache since it should be aligned. So in that sense you do not waste any bytes in the cache for an AVX register. That also kind of preempt the argument that spreading those on the stack would be a problem since they are exactly aligned and thus a read or a write will always be exactly the necessary data for the register.

Comment: @EOF, I used 12kb as an example. Various manufacturers use various sizes anyway... I fixed the "frame buffer".

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt, I have written matrix multiplication code which uses 9 or 10 SSE/AVX registers. When I compile in 32-bit mode and run it I see a significant drop in efficiency in 32-bit mode. Probably I can do this with less than 8 registers using register renaming. You may be able to use less registers than you think.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: I was really more concerned with the assertion that code and data share a common L1 cache. That's been false for most micro-architectures for a long time, since the von-Neumann bottleneck *bites* when instruction fetch has to share a cache with data fetch.

Comment: @EOF, Really? Xeon E7 datasheet volume 1, here https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-e7-8800-4800-2800-families-vol-1-datasheet.html , on page 9 it shows their cache specs: L1 has 32Kb of instructions, and 16Kb or data. Whether it is separated is not shown there, but it is not unlikely to be shown as 48Kb of L1 in end users specs. Or am I looking at a document about very old technology again?

Comment: @AlexisWilke When you read `n kb L1i, m kb L1d` or equivalent, that means there are two *seperate* caches for instructions and data. I'm quite sure that Xeon has two L1 caches.

Comment: @EOF, I agree, however, it is often that they show the total of L1 caches in one number in specs. Actually, the plain specs for that process is something like 347Mb of cache. Not specifying how much of L1, L2 and L3... So you have to be careful and check closely as the 48Kb is not just data (in case that's what you found.) Actually, many high end servers have separated banks of RAM too, making them much faster at running separate processes since each bank can truly be accessed in parallel.

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant. I couldn't even imagine anyone quoting the sum of the caches in their processor documentation, it seems like a meaningless number to me.

Comment: I guess I have read somewhere that reading/writing to/from any cache has same throughput, only latency is higher for high-level caches. It means that if you are doing a long loop with independent iterations, then it is probably not a problem since CPU can do some calculations while waiting for data to arrive.